# Ccache hit rate 0.00 % in GitHub Actions CI

Tags: c++, macos, github-actions, azerothcore, ccache

In [our C++ project](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk), we managed to setup [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) building our sources using [ccache](https://ccache.dev/).

It works very well on Linux where, thanks to `ccache`, the build succeeds in less than 5 minutes.

Unfortunately, when trying to build on macOS, `ccache` doesn't seem to work, giving:

```
cache directory                     /Users/runner/.ccache
primary config                      /Users/runner/.ccache/ccache.conf
secondary config      (readonly)    /usr/local/Cellar/ccache/3.7.11_1/etc/ccache.conf
stats updated                       Sun Aug 23 11:57:31 2020
cache hit (direct)                     0
cache hit (preprocessed)               0
cache miss                          7175
cache hit rate                      0.00 %
cache file missing                     1
cleanups performed                  2976
files in cache                       165
cache size                         422.4 MB
max cache size                     500.0 MB
```

[image: AzerothCore macOS ccache issue]

Consequently, the macOS build takes about 40 minutes to finish.

- Example of a build: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/runs/1018358261
- This is where the actions are defined: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/.github/workflows/core_build.yml
- The entire project's source code is publicly available at: https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk

So despite I've tried to setup the `macOS` build the same way of the `ubuntu-*` ones, I've failed to get ccache properly working and I can't figure out why.

How to make `ccache` work with `macOS` too?

Comment: Start by logging which compiler option were used when building the code. ccache will refuse to cache a build if it sees a compiler option it believes means that the build cannot be cached.

Comment: You’re using GitHub sha on the key. This sha will change on every commit you do, therefore it will always miss when you try to get a cache hit that includes commit hash.

Comment: @EdwardRomero has the real answer, I think.  Please post it as such.  Also, Github, please post a recipe for this common use case.  Even something terribly simple like sharing a single ccache for all branches of the repo would likely suit many projects and save GH Actions many cycles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is most likely that *max cache size* is too small. If the results (mostly object files) from a build do not fit in *max cache size* then no usable results will be left for the next build and you will only get cache misses.

*cleanups performed* was 2976 before the build and 3353 after the build, so 377 [automatic cleanups](https://ccache.dev/manual/3.7.11.html#_automatic_cleanup) were performed. Since *max cache size* was 500 MB, each cleanup removed around 500 * (1 - 0.8) / 16 MB = 6.25 MB and all cleanups together therefore removed around 377 * 6.25 MB ≈ 2356 MB of data. That should be approximately the size of the results of one build. (0.8 is the default "limit_multiple" and 16 refers to the number of subdirectories in the cache.)

Try to increase the cache size limit substantially. Based on the above calculation, a good cache size would be at least 5 GB. You could also or alternatively enable compression (`CCACHE_COMPRESS=1`) to fit more results in the cache.